# How to install Gnome 3 on Debian Squeeze (Gnome 2)?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome3

I would like to remove my Gnome 2 desktop to replace it with Gnome 3, because I do not want to update to Debian Wheezy. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in response to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40373/):

I would NOT install every .deb separately - this is a terrible idea and there are much better ways. Plus the guide is quite outdated, although on the right track. You should look, as said in the link, into apt-pinning. But don't use experimental, testing is already on gnome 3.4 and will save you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you're looking for : http://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/06/16/installing-gnome-3-on-debian-6-0-squeeze-no-sorry/

That blog suggests using Experimental debian repos and fetching Gnome 3 from there

I'm not sure, but chances are you could also get every .deb (including gnome 3 deps... good luck!) one by one from the newer debian releases, then install with dpkg.

Comment: well, the guy doesn't want to use Wheezy, as that blog suggests